# is signed type suppose to be 32-bit?

Tags: c

I am testing on C data size with following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXOF(n) (typeof(n))(-1)

#define hexfmt "%#lx"

#define printtype(n) \
{\
    n _a; \
    printf("%25s \t(%d bytes)\t " hexfmt "\n",#n,sizeof(n), MAXOF(_a) );\
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printtype(signed char);
    printtype(unsigned char);

    printtype(signed short);
    printtype(unsigned short);

    printtype(signed short int);
    printtype(unsigned short int);

    printtype(signed int);
    printtype(unsigned int);

    printtype(signed);
    printtype(unsigned);

    printtype(signed long);
    printtype(unsigned long);

    printtype(signed long int);
    printtype(unsigned long int);

    printtype(signed long long);
    printtype(unsigned long long);

    printtype(signed long long int);
    printtype(unsigned long long int);

    return 0;
}
```

here is the output

Tested with gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

```
           signed char       (1 bytes)        0xffffffff
         unsigned char       (1 bytes)        0xff
          signed short       (2 bytes)        0xffffffff
        unsigned short       (2 bytes)        0xffff
      signed short int       (2 bytes)        0xffffffff
    unsigned short int       (2 bytes)        0xffff
            signed int       (4 bytes)        0xffffffff
          unsigned int       (4 bytes)        0xffffffff
                signed       (4 bytes)        0xffffffff
              unsigned       (4 bytes)        0xffffffff
           signed long       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
         unsigned long       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
       signed long int       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
     unsigned long int       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
      signed long long       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
    unsigned long long       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
  signed long long int       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
unsigned long long int       (8 bytes)        0xffffffffffffffff
```

Although the sizeof(signed char) is 1 bytes the representation when using printf is 0xffffffff (which is 4 bytes). Is that mean signed type always be 32bits?

Comment: `x` is not a valid conversion specifier for a signed integer.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) `"If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."`

Comment: No, it means all integer types smaller than `int` are converted to `int` when passed to a variadic function. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions But yes, you need to use a correct conversion specifier anyway.

Comment: It's not safe to use `%d` to print a `sizeof` value.  Depending on the machine, `sizeof` may have a different size from an `int`.

Comment: `%zu` for `sizeof`

Comment: Why don't you use the constants in `limits.h`? -- What makes you think that `-1` for a signed integer returns the *maximum*?

Comment: @thebusybee it have corrsponding macro but I couldn't think I could create a dynamic macro for randome type. Like `__u32 len` and `__u16 len`

Comment: @Ry- if there is implicit conversion, why `(signed short) (-1)` which equal to `(unsigned short) 0xFF` is converted to `(unsigned int) 0xFFFFFFFF` instead of `(unsigned int) 0x000000FF`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so is there any specifier that match all data type?, or any way to dynamic the specifier?

Comment: @Silver I hesitate to say no, but only because I don't know of a way to do it in a clean manner. C++11 introduce the `_Generic` macro that does allow some generalization of functions, but beyond that, there isn't much that is type agnostic in C. Type controls everything, pointer arithmetic, etc.. Even `typeof` isn't standard C, that is a GNU extension, but just knowing the type of something, doesn't adjust the remaining aspects of the code. You could do elaborate lookups based on it, but honestly, I've never found any real generic way to do it.

Comment: @Silver: `(int)(signed short)(-1) != (int)(unsigned short)0xFFFF` (when `int` is larger than `short`, and assuming you meant `0xFFFF` instead of `0xFF`)